# PHP - Display only the elements that time has not passed JSON FILE

Tags: php

I have this json file:

[Json Blob File](https://jsonblob.com/eef6078b-3664-11e7-ae4c-2775614e7078)

Every element has a property call time , so I just want display the elements in the array that time has not passed of today.

If in the array the element time is 12:00 PM, but the real time is 12:30 PM, 
It means that it has already passed and can not be shown!

Comment: i can give you the logic but you need to try to code atleast something, after that if you are stuck we can help, but its not possible to write up the whole code for you. first convert the json to array by json_decode, then loop it and check array[keys]['time'] > time_now, then inside if print it

Comment: time_now ? , yes i try some code but do not work .. @Exprator